# putting if exists as a condition in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I can't find answers in Google because I don't know the keyword... so this is my query

```
SELECT col1 
from table1
WHERE col2 in (select col2 from table2 where user_id=@ID)
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to put if conditional statements... if table2 is null then i'd pull this condition instead

```
select col1 from table1 <no condition>
```

like if `select col2 from table2 where user_id=@id is null` then it'll pull out all the data

can someone help me?

Comment: *if table2 is null...* - you mean, its empty? How it could be null...?

Comment: What do you mean by "Table2 is null"? Do you mean it is empty or that you are passing the table name to a procedure and using dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.col1 
FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.col2 = table1.col2 AND table2.user_id = @ID
```

Comment: Also, with JOINS, `col1` might be an ambiguous name, by always adding the table (or alias) name it is easy to save literally hours during a year not having to repeat queries, or restart builds and tests caused by that mistake. Also, if the DB schema changes, and in the future, table2.col1 gets introduced, which should normally be a harmless change will break a your app. And that is not welcome - takes ages to clear up if there are no tests for it...

Comment: Sorry, but he stated that "if `select col2 from table2 where user_id=@id is null` then it'll pull out all the data. And I interpreted that as "If there is no record in table2 for the user id, then he wants to get all data from table1". And that is exactly what the outer join does.

Comment: @ppeterka You are right with the table name, I edited my statement.

Comment: @FrankPI thinking about it: you're right. Damn language barrier, I completely misinterpreted `<no condition>` for something like 1=0, which is false all the time... And by `pulling all the` results I thought he'd want to pull it out from the result set - so no rows get returned... I might just learn English someday I think...

Comment: wahahaha... sorry bout that... anyway, if table2 has rows.. then table1 will only pull those that has the same col2 from table 2 only, but if table2 is null or didn't return any rows... then table1 will pull everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(500)

SET @sql = 'SELECT col1 from table1'
IF((select col2 from table2 where user_id=@ID )IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE col2 in (select col2 from table2 where user_id= ' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR) + ' )'
END
EXEC (@sql)
```

You can use dynamic query for this case according to your requirement

Comment: How would this perform when compared to @FrankPI-s solution?

Comment: Sorry No details but, generally dynamic query is good when we want only the required part of query to be executed

Comment: @brykneval Your statement is valid, but out of place. On this site, you often have to guess what the poster _really_ wants to achieve to give real help. If someone asked you `How to hit nails into hardwood with a soft cover book while having a hammer in my other hand?` What would you recommend? `Try hitting it with the spine of the book.` or `Put the book down, and use the hammer`?

Comment: I think the solution is to the point, the condition in IF only execute when its not null, else it return the whole value as stated in this condition >select col1 from table1 <no condition>
like if select col2 from table2 where user_id=@id is null then it'll pull out all the data

Comment: @brykneval Excuse me, it's maybe the language barrier kicking in again... The problem is not with the dynamic query itself, but why didn't you use `JOIN` instead of the subquery?

Comment: I don't prefer joins until its necessary, the thing is clean code and selecting the specific parts